# Can not transfer to an array in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring

When registering a user, I want to immediately define the role for it, for this I added a scroll, but since the roles field in Java is an array, I pass this value as an array, and so, I cannot understand why this value is not assigned

```
<div class="bloc">
    <select name="role" size="">
        <option value=["ROLE_USER"] ng-model="user.roles">ROLE_USER</option>
        <option value=["ROLE_SUPPORT"] ng-model="user.roles">ROLE_SUPPORT</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

As you understand, I cannot add a user like that, but if I add `$scope.user.roles = ["ROLE_USER"]` in the controller;
then the value is assigned to the roles field, and no problems arise, what would you advise on this issue? I get 400 error.
Can send more info if needed

---

```
<option value=["ROLE_USER"] ng-options="user.roles">ROLE_USER</option>
```

> is it right version?

---

```
<label>Color grouped by shade, with some disabled:
    <select ng-model="myColor"
            ng-options="color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors">
    </select>
</label><br />
```

> that example from link

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<option>` elements. See [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: <option value=["ROLE_USER"] ng-options="user.roles">ROLE_USER</option>

Comment: is it right version?

Comment: The `ng-options` directive belongs on the `<select>` element. It does not work with the `<option>` element. See [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: <label>Color grouped by shade, with some disabled:
    <select ng-model="myColor"
          ng-options="color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors">
    </select>
  </label><br/>

Comment: that example from link